# How to measure the magnitude of a change in distribution across time

Tags: time-series, distributions, statistical-significance, descriptive-statistics

I have a dataset where rows are individuals and I want to measure the magnitude of the change in the distribution of their spending from year to year.

**So for Person A:**

- T1 his values are: 30% A 30% B and 40% C
- T2 his values are: 90% A 5%  B and 5% C

I want to create a measure that will indicate the magnitude of the change that takes into account the change in proportion for each category.

---

**EDIT** Added more details below:

- I have data for around 80K observations and 15 time points for each observation. Essentially I want to identify meaningful deviations in their spending behavior. So, to start, I figured I would need calculate the change from t1 to t2. Later, I except I will have to look at longer periods, but for right now I wanted to keep it as simple as possible
- I'm using this measure as a way to gauge an individuals priorities in terms of how they allocate their money. So if someone who has allocated just 10% of their spending on Category A in T1 but then it becomes 90% in T2. This is more meaningful to me then a person to goes from 70% to 90% during the same time period. I know I could look at simple percent change for each category, but I wasn't sure if there was a more robust way to identify how large the change in behavior is across all of the categories

Comment: Without knowing what would count as a good measure for your scientific question this is very broad. Can you expand on what properties you are aiming for?

Comment: How many years of data do you have? How many individuals are there? By analogy to time series of normal data, there can be a great deal of volatility around a relatively stable trend & little volatility around a rapidly changing trend. Which are you looking for here? W/ 3 categories, the data are multidimensional which means there are different kinds of changes that can occur. Can you specify what type might interest you? (Eg, if you were interested in A vs ~A, then [30, 20, 50] = [30, 60, 10].)

Comment: @mdewey I have data for around 80K observations and 15 time points for each observation. Essentially I want to identify meaningful deviations in their spending behavior. So, to start, I figured I would need calculate the change from t1 to t2. Later, I except I will have to look at longer periods, but for right now I wanted to keep it as simple as possible.

Comment: @gung I'm using this measure as a way to gauge an individuals priorities in terms of how they allocate their money. So if someone who has allocated just 10% of their spending on Category A in T1 but then it becomes 90% in T2. This is more meaningful to me then a person to goes from 70% to 90% during the same time period.

I know I could look at simple percent change for each category, but I wasn't sure if there was a more robust way to identify how large the change in behavior is across all of the categories.

Answer (score 1):

For each category ; for each person .... develop a robust ARIMA model for their annual absolute spending incorporating unknown deterministic structure (pulses/level shifts/local time trends) . Now assess if there is a pulse in the most recent period. If there is a pulse then flag this spending as exceptional. A caveat .. if their annual income is changing one has to possibly analyze the data conditionally upon their income thus a transfer function model would be in order.

Comment: The strong heteroscedasticity and perfect correlation among the three series suggest the approach you recommend is likely to fail.  Predictions won't sum to 100% and extremely small or large values will get more weight than they deserve.

Comment: I had suggested (meant) using the observed spending ( observed spending) not the percent change.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification--I had overlooked that distinction, which you clearly expressed as "annual *absolute* spending."